# Updating a MySQL View via Entity Framework = "Every derived table must have its own alias"

Tags: asp.net, mysql, entity-framework

I am trying to update a MySQL view via Entity framework and getting the error "Every derived table must have its own alias".

Any ideas on how I can change my view to prevent this? Here's my MySQL view code:

```
    select 
  a.compid AS compid,
  a.loid AS loid,
  a.purchase_rate AS purchase_rate,
  a.purchase_min AS purchase_min,
  a.purchase_max AS purchase_max,
  a.refi_rate AS refi_rate,
  a.refi_min AS refi_min,
  a.refi_max AS refi_max,
  a.quarter AS quarter,
  a.year AS year,
  a.changed_on AS changed_on,
  a.user_changed AS user_changed,
  a.is_active AS is_active,
  a.notes_id AS notes_id,
  b.branch AS branchID,
  b.name AS lo_name,
  c.branch_name_friendly AS branchname 
from ((encompassdata.comp a 
  inner join default.users_encompass b on
    (
      (a.loid = b.un_enc)
    )) 
  inner join default.branch_info c on
    (
      (b.branch = c.branch_id)
    ))
```

Comment: What's up with all those parentheses after `FROM`?  From what I can tell none of them are needed.

Comment: Yeah...the parenthesis auto-generate when I create the view in the MySQL management tool I use. I just created the view without them and am still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Try to ditch all the parenthesis in the `FROM` clause

```
SELECT a.compid AS compid,
       ...
  FROM encompassdata.comp a INNER JOIN
       default.users_encompass b on a.loid = b.un_enc INNER JOIN
       default.branch_info c on b.branch = c.branch_id
```